# Почему не проходит Экстернализация?

Tags: java, сериализация

Мне нужно сериализовать объект класса Help. Класс содержит только одно поле: BufferedImage. Класс имплементирует интерфейс java.io.Externalizable и поэтому выглядит так:

```
public class Help implements Externalizable {
    public BufferedImage about;
    Help(BufferedImage about){
            this.about = about;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(about);
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        about = (BufferedImage) in.readObject();
    }
}
```

Для сериализации вызываю метод

```
    private void externalizableWriteAbout() {
        myHelp = new Help(about);

        try(FileOutputStream myOutFile2 = new FileOutputStream ("about.dat"); 
            BufferedOutputStream myOutBuffer2 = new BufferedOutputStream(myOutFile2);
            ObjectOutputStream myOutObject2 = new ObjectOutputStream(myOutBuffer2); ){
            myOutObject2.writeObject(myHelp);

        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

В результате вызова этого метода получаю:  - **java.io.NotSerializableException: java.awt.image.BufferedImage**

Подскажите, в чём ошибка? Как исправить?

Comment: ошибка в подходе к реализации. класс BufferedImage не имплементирует интерфейсов, делающих его сериализируемым, отсюда исключение. но в целом вы очень странным способом разбили все на классы и методы. мало того, зачем вам сохранять BufferedImage ? это класс работает с изображениями, а они , как не крути, являются  файлами. сохранять надо не объект BufferedImage , а информацию (картинку), которую вы прочитали. сам объект BufferedImage  полезной нагрузки точно не несет, чтобы его сохранять

Comment: В принципе в этом и состоит вопрос: как сериализовать классы, которые описаны в java и не содержат интерфейса Serialization? Я просто создал класс для изучения способа сериализации и пробую разные варианты. Я хочу узнать как мне нужно поступить если класс описан в java и необходимо его сериализовать.

Comment: вы можете мне объяснить, зачем вам это делать? можете на конкретном примере

Comment: У меня в программе для сохранения состояния игры нужно сериализовать объект класса который содержит много разных полей, в том числе и BufferedImage. Было бы очень удобно сериализовать его весь (в том числе и поле BufferedImage). Я понимаю, что можно сохранить его отдельно в виде картинки. Но это лишний код, лишние переменные, лишние методы. Не хотелось бы так делать. Поэтому я ищу способ сделать это одной операцией. Сохранил при выходе, загрузил при запуске. Просто и понятно. Для этого хочу разобраться с этим вопросом на простом примере.

Comment: Я перед этим спрашивал как добиться такого результата с помощью интерфейса Serialization. Мне ответили, что с помощью Serialization не получится, а вот Externalizable может это сделать. Я попробовал разобраться сам, но не получилось. Поэтому и спросил: как же всё-таки с помощью Externalizable сериализовать встроенный класс java?

Comment: все верно, просто вы не разобрались , в чем отличие между этими интерфейсами. Externalizable дает вам в руки механизм управления сериализацией. это не отменяет того, что классы, которые не имплементируют эти 2 интерфейса, не могут быть сериализованы. просто тепрь вы можете вытянуть информацию из этого объекта руками, сохранить его, а потом при чтении из это информации создать объект. посему, если быть очент настойчивым, то вы, разумеется, сохраните этот объект. никто не может помешать вам выстрелит в ногу, если вы так настаиваете на этом.

Comment: Куда уж более настойчиво, но выстрелить не получается )

Comment: так и слава богу! у вас есть какой-то объект. судя по всему большой, при этом он инкапсулирует в себя такие вещи, как BufferedImage. и нам его еще и на диск потребовалось сохранять. может надо пересмотреть структуру классов с точки зрения GRASP? сделать сервис леер и использовать бд для хранения данных? это для начала... а стрельнуть в ногу еще успеете

Comment: Согласен с вами. Надо подумать